# Override the google custom search css

Tags: search, google-custom-search

In my site have google custom search. I have an issue with the font of the search result. I need **Arial,sans-serif** .

Here is my google search code.

```
<div id="cse-search-results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var googleSearchIframeName = "cse-search-results";
  var googleSearchFormName = "cse-search-box";
  var googleSearchFrameWidth = 600;
  var googleSearchDomain = "www.google.com";
  var googleSearchPath = "/cse";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

Here is my css comes from google.

```
.gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result {
    font-family: font;
}
.gsc-control-cse, .gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

.gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result this class was override the font-family of below class.

Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked into CSS, but I think you are following a very old example. Google now have a customizable search engine creator, in which you can specify which color and font you wanted for each element

See [image]

Also, you can define this in code by using a context XML file, the detail of which is available in the [Look and Feel section](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ui_xml)

Comment: Linked custom search also uses a context XML `<form id="cref" action="http://www.google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cref" value="http://www.guha.com/cref_cse.xml" />`, with which you can specify the look and feel, like this `<LookAndFeel nonprofit="false" googlebranding="watermark"
      element_layout="1" theme="1" custom_theme="false" text_font="Arial, sans-serif"/>
    <Logo />`

Answer (score 2):

thanks lemondrop worked perfectly
I changed

```
.gs-result .gs-title,
.gs-result .gs-title * {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', Tahoma, sans-serif; 
}
```

to

```
.gs-result .gs-title,
.gs-result .gs-title * {
    color: black !important;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', Tahoma, sans-serif !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly cant you just use !important for the one you want to override like so:

```
font-family: Arial,sans-serif !important;
```

Comment: Well I dont really understand what you are trying to do exactly, could you explain a bit more.

Comment: Actually the css is from google. If we apply font-family: Arial,sans-serif !important; this css. It doesn't accept