# Internal CSS not override external CSS (api google)... why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not understand why internal css does not overwrite the external css created by google ...
This external css need to create the Google search bar (in my case, only serves to create a results page-SERP)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript">    </script>
        <style type="text/css">     

        .gs-result .gs-title, .gs-result .gs-title * {      
        }

        .gs-result a.gs-visibleUrl, .gs-result .gs-visibleUrl {
            color: #008000;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: none;
        }

        .gsc-table-result {
            font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        </style>              
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

         google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata);
         google.load('search', '1');    
         // other js-code that works ;)
        </script>
      </head>
```

why ???

thanks!

**EDIT**

the result page is created by google cse and is added in my div.. this the code created:

```
<div id="cse"> //my div
 <div class="gsc-control-cse gsc-control-cse-it"> //here there is a google code... i show you only parents beacause the code is too long
 <div class="gsc-control-wrapper-cse" dir="ltr" style="visibility: visible;">
</div>
```

Here there is a part of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/2rg86vm6/1/

is only a part so doesn't work ;)

Comment: Does `!important` work? Then you might have a lower Specificity.

Comment: What do you mean by "external css created by google". If it's an iframe the answer is you can't.

Comment: Is it loading it into an iframe? in which case your internal css will have no effect on the iframe content

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: @Ionut how i can know if is an iframe?

Comment: @alirezasafian sorry but the code is too long and is composed by two pages (beacause is there a form)

Comment: @user3162975 Can you give the link of that page?

Comment: @user3162975, use inspect element and see if ".gs-result a.gs-visibleUrl", and other classes like those are in an iframe tag.

Comment: ahhh ok are not in iframe tag ...:/ so?

Comment: Most probably is an iframe. Post a link to your website.

Comment: @alirezasafian no beacuse i'm work in local file with notepad, but i can you post a jsfiddle where is a part of my code (but doesn't work beacause i tell you, my code is composede by two pages - 1 page where i have a search bar and put a keyword, and 2° page where there is a search but is created also a result page by google cse): http://jsfiddle.net/2rg86vm6/1/

Comment: @Ionut ok one moment and i edit the question

Comment: @user3162975, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738670/override-the-google-custom-search-css

Comment: see edit.... @Ionut i read that the accepted question suggest to use a panel to customize, but in the panel there a few options... other answers suggest to use !important

Comment: @user3162975 Please, fix your jsfiddle.

Comment: @alirezasafian i can't is too long, sorry

Comment: @Ionut with !important works... if you write an answer, i will acept it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `!important` on your code, altough I would not encourage you to do that permanently, use it just for testing (better way is to strenghten your selector):

```css
.gs-result a.gs-visibleUrl, .gs-result .gs-visibleUrl {
            color: #008000 !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            display: none !important;
        }
```

Comment: Never use `!important`.  Always strengthen your selector.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "Why isn't my CSS being applied?" is almost always that some other style definition is overriding it.  When this happens, it can be frustrating, but don't despair: There are only 2 things you need to know:

1. Understand selector strength and CSS specificity.
2. Know how to use your browser's developer tools.

### CSS Specificity and selector strength

The "selector" is the part of your style definition that targets (or "selects") your element.  It's the code that comes before the curly braces in your CSS:

```
.gs-results {
    color: #008000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}
```

The above snippet represents a single CSS rule.  The selector for the above rule is `.gs-results`.

Selector strength is important when you have two rules that match a single element and the styles conflict:

```css
.a { color: blue; }
p  { color: red; }
```

```html
<p class="a">Am I red or am I blue?</p>
```

In the above example, the text is blue because a class selector has a higher specificity than an element selector. If you wanted to force the text red, you could strengthen your `p` selector by adding the class to it:

```css
.a  { color: blue; }
p.a { color: red; }
```

```html
<p class="a">Am I red or am I blue?</p>
```

Now the text will be red because a selector consisting of element and class has a higher specificity than just a class selector.  We can make in blue again, by increasing the specificity of the first selector.  For example, specifying an ancestor class:

```css
.x .a { color: blue; }
p.a   { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="x">
    <p class="a">Am I red or am I blue?</p>
</div>
```

Further reading:

- [CSS Standard: Calculating specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)  The algorithm is actually quite simple.
- [CSS Specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

### Finding conflicting selectors

Understanding specificity is vital, but only helpful if you know the style rule that is overriding your own.  Fortunately, every browser comes with excellent developer tools that make discovering applied rules a breeze.

In any browser, right click the element whose styles are not being applied as you expected, and choose "Inspect Element".  This will open the developer tools with the DOM inspector open and the clicked element selected.  You may have to manually select a parent or child element of the one that is selected.  Once you have the correct element selected, look at the rules that are being applied.  You should see yours in the list with the style properties in strikethrough:

[image: chrome developer tools]

If your particular element has a lot of style rules applied and you are having trouble finding the CSS property you care about, try the "Computed" tab.  Additionally, Chrome let's you filter the styles displayed by entering the property you are interested in where it says "Filter...".  IE let's you filter the computed tab.

Now that you have identified what rule is overriding your styles, you can see how you need to strengthen your selector.  This should not be a difficult thing.  We will get our text back to red by borrowing from the other rule's selector:

```css
.x .a  { color: blue; }
.x p.a { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="x">
    <p class="a">Am I red or am I blue?</p>
</div>
```

### Why not just use `!important`?

[Stephanie Rewis's tweet](https://twitter.com/stefsull/status/70631020352913408) says it best:

> #### Using !important in your CSS usually means you're narcissistic & selfish or lazy. Respect the devs to come...

It causes maintenance headaches.  If this is code you will ever need to maintain, you will hate yourself later for using `!important`.  If other devs need to maintain it, they will hate you.